# Is there such a thing as a white laser pointer?

Tags: visible-light, laser

I can't seem to find a white laser pointer for sale anywhere. Is it just me or is it somehow not possible to make it? I see only color laser pointers like red, green, blue, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to make.
white is a mixture of all the visible spectrum whereas a laser can only be of a single wavelength (ie a single color in the rainbow)

See Wikipedia [white light article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White#White_light) for more details on white light

Comment: Technically the white color only requires 3 spectrum lines able to excite the 3 color receptors of the retina, not the entire spectrum.

Comment: This depends if you refer to white as perceive from the human eye or white from a physical point of view. If I wanted a "white" laser I would assume it has a continuous spectrum like a white lamp.

Comment: Like this laser:
https://www.nktphotonics.com/lasers-fibers/product-category/supercontinuum-lasers/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0Z-koP_w6wIVuD6tBh2KcgwgEAAYASAAEgJd1_D_BwE

Comment: OP wants to get a white pointer, do you seriously believe they are interested in getting a pointer that produces white electromagnetic radiations from a physical point of view?

Answer (score 0):

A laser produces monochromatic light. White light contains at least three colors (red, green, blue), so you would need 3 laser beams to produce something white (or shift between the 3 colors fast enough). Lasers are not LEDs (the latter can be white).

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, is there a way to make your own white laser "pointer"? For example, I understand that the color of the smartphone is white. Can we then use this light and somehow direct it in a way that it can project itself in a narrow and straight manner at a distance (to make it appear like a laser as much as possible)?

Comment: While LED lighting often uses phosphors to convert UV to broad spectrum white light, there are proposed (and demonstrated) 'white' LED lights that use three (or more) colored LEDs to create white light. I guess that, in theory, one could mix three laser colors in the right proportion to get something that is kind of white.

Comment: Why in theory? There are projectors using 3 laser beams to display color movies. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_projector

Comment: @Mac_79: the backlight used behind smartphone screens is not a laser.